# get UDID of Android device via adobe air

Tags: android, air, udid

How can I get UDID of Android device via adobe air? I want to get UDID of my device with Android OS installed on it via Adobe AIR. How can I do it? Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like it's in the APIs. You can try generating a random code and storing it on the device. This has been asked before here: [Get unique identifier (MAC address, UDID, etc...) in Adobe AIR for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794493/get-unique-identifier-mac-address-udid-etc-in-adobe-air-for-ios) and recently here: http://www.flexdeveloper.eu/forums/actionscript-3-0/detecting-unique-device-number-in-adobe-flex-like-udid-of-iphone-device/

Comment: so, I can only get MAC address but not UDID??

Comment: Through the Adobe Flex platform, yes. You can generate and store your own random value, though, which accomplishes just about the same thing in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()` to get udid of a device.

Add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

you can refer this doc:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29

also check:

[Unique ID of Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468248/unique-id-of-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly on AdobeAir. But you may build an ANE to do just that. You may want to have a look at this other solution we have posted here, with the the required ANE for this purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43338213/247658