# get Device id in Adobe Air

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, air-android

**For get device id in android sdk i wrote simple This code ::**

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

**but i need it in `Adobe air` app. how can i do that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can now use Native Extensions on other platforms other than TV with AIR 3.0.

Info: [Extending Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/extending-air.html)

API:  [flash.external.ExtensionContext](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExtensionContext.html)

Answer (score 0):

We have recently developed an ANE that has tried to solve this problem by giving you access to different device identifiers. You can try the ANE here https://github.com/myflashlab/UDID-ANE

The ANE provides you with the following Identifiers:

- Android ID
- Serial Number
- Telephony Device ID
- Telephony Subscriber ID
- UUID
- Unique Vendor ID

---

```
import com.myflashlab.air.extensions.udid.UDID;

UDID.init();
if(UDID.OS == UDID.ANDROID) 
{
    trace(UDID.androidId);
}
else if(UDID.OS == UDID.IOS) 
{
    trace(UDID.vendorId);
}
```

---

Comment: I dont get it, is it free or paid ane?

Comment: @mrahmat There is a demo version for free on the github.