# Getting Mobile Device's ID in Actionscript

Tags: android, actionscript, air

I am developing a mobile app using Adobe AIR(Action Script). How can I get the Device ID of the mobile phone or tablet which the app has been running. Anyone could please help me in this.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get Device id in Adobe Air](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979300/get-device-id-in-adobe-air)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [get Device id in Adobe Air](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979300/get-device-id-in-adobe-air)

Also I am not so sure how is with the apple user/developert agreement, I think accessing the UID on iOS is not more or will not more be allowed.

In case you want to build some ANE to read this from iPhone you can use this code

http://www.redcodelabs.com/2009/06/objective-c-get-iphone-device-guid/

Comment: If this is a duplicate question; then I recommend voting to close using the 'duplicate' option.  Your extra link is a nice extra info, though.